# Install wireless driver for an HP ProBook 4525s

Tags: drivers, wireless

I need to install the wifi driver to ubuntu. so I [downloaded the driver](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DriverDownload.jsp?prodNameId=4173724&lang=en&cc=fr&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=4173615&taskId=135) from hp website but the extension is .rpm, so I need to convert him to .deb so I can install it on ubuntu.

The problem is I don't have internet connection on ubuntu to do this :

```
sudo apt-get install alien
```

How can convert the driver on windows for example, or how can I do download alien and place it under my usb to install it after booting on ubuntu.

It's an HP ProBook 4525s with this two drivers :

Pilote LAN sans fil Ralink

Pilote LAN sans fil Broadcom

Comment: What wifi card (or computer model) do you have? Perhaps there is an other solution available.

Comment: see updates ...

Comment: Can you add some hardware information to your question? You can find out what logs and commands to use here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Answer (score 1):

Ask a friend or in a linux/ubuntu forum for help in converting the driver - if the license doesn't prohibit it, of course.

Comment: Who votes me down without comment?

Comment: I vote you up. Even when people don't value the words of wisdom on this days, it is wise to know when to ask for help. Oh! Isn't this place for "look for help"? ... However... Ignorants uses to down vote with no commenting.

Comment: Thank you much. I still would like to know what is bad in my idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can (possibly, depending on your circumstances) download the file `alien_8.81_all.deb` onto a removable medium (e.g. USB key) from http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/alien (assuming that you are running 10.10 — if not, change 'maverick' to your release name).

To install that file from ubuntu, run `dpkg --install /path/to/it/alien_8.81_all.deb` from a terminal window.  This is mostly the same as running `apt-get install alien`.

Comment: So, what about the dependency hell!